# htaccess config to block on browser agent

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[htaccess config to block depending on browser agent](https://serverfault.com/questions/253419/htaccess-config-to-block-depending-on-browser-agent)

how is the opposite done of this code ?

for example inhibition of `^.Chrome/10.$` entry

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to contains the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Chrome/10.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Firefox/4.*$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/browsererror.html [R,L]
```

This *allows* requests from user agents that match the pattern `^.*Chrome/10.*$` or `^.*Firefox/4.*$`. It does this by essentially doing nothing (`- [L]`) when these requests reach your site and redirecting otherwise.

To do the exact opposite and block requests from these user agents by redirecting then just remove the second `RewriteRule` and redirect in the first:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Chrome/10.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Firefox/4.*$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/browsererror.html [R,L]
```

However, this isn't necessarily the "best way" to block requests from specific user-agents. Instead of using mod_rewrite, consider using mod_setenvif and the appropriate mod_authz... module (depending on whether you are on Apache 2.2 or 2.4). And serve a 403 Forbidden instead of redirecting. For example:

- [Blocking apache access via user agent string](https://serverfault.com/questions/251988/blocking-apache-access-via-user-agent-string)